# Sorting an Excel list using VBA is not working

Tags: list, sorting, excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm trying to sort a series of lists alphabetically by a column called "Name". The below code is compliling without error, and running without error, but it is not sorting the lists.

Can anyone help at all?

```
'**
 ' Sorts the defined list using the definded parameters
 ''
Function sort_list(list_name As String, column_name As String, Optional sort_order As String = xlAscending)

Dim list As ListObject          ' The list that is to be sorted
Dim sort_column As Range        ' The column in the list that is to be used as the sort key

    ' Set the list and the sort column
    Set list = WS_ext.ListObjects(list_name)
    Set sort_column = list.ListColumns(column_name).Range

    ' Sort the list
    With list.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add sort_column, sort_order
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Apply
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: try optional sort_order as variant = xlAscending, I think setting this as a string it gets interpreted as "1" instead of 1

Comment: No joy unfortunately. Even putting `.SortFields.Add sort_column, xlAscending` fails, although still runs and causes no errors. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that I didn't specify which arguments were which for the `SortFields` function. Changing that line to the below fixed my problem.

```
.SortFields.Add Key:=sort_column, order:=Sort_order
```